# Android TextToSpeech Initialization - Set default TTS engine as "android.speech.tts"

Tags: android-intent, intentfilter, google-text-to-speech

I am working on android's TextToSpeech engine. Initialization code is

```
TextToSpeech mTTS;
mTTS=new TextToSpeech(this, this, "android.speech.tts");
mTTS.setEngineByPackageName("android.speech.tts");

Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();

checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);

startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

but this code a Chooser dialog box on my phone to choose b/w Google's TextToSpeech Engine or Samsung TextToSpeech Engine. Now i want to remove this

[image: Chooser popup]

Chooser box and load the Google's TTS engine directly without user interaction. Please help i am stucked :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Intent (TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA) I believe you are trying to check if TTS data is installed on device or not. By the way, this will check for default device language if not installed it will give **resultCode** as **TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA** onActivityResult().

Please find below a proper way of initializing TTS and handling errors.

```
system = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
system.setRecognitionListener(this);
speech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result = speech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not available, attempting download");
                        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                        installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                        startActivity(installIntent);
                    }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed!");
            }
        }
    }, "com.google.android.tts");
```

Please note 3 points here:

1. The package name is "com.google.android.tts" to use Google Text To Speech.
2. You dont need to check for intent "ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA", that will be handled in **onInit()**.
3. The Text to Speech setlanguage is an expensive operation, it freezes the UI thread; if you wish to use the default language please remove it.

Using this method you will not get any pop ups for dialogs and tts will be initialized. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Will not install this long
Or
Locks the screen?

Comment: Exactly which part of your code, avoid opening the popup for choice tts engine?

Comment: Point 1 mentioned in my answer. The package name decides which engine will be used hence you won't see the engine selection dialog.

Comment: thanks. But in my project, despite the choice of engine, the popup opens! Of course I do not have the first two lines in my project, exactly what do these two lines?

Comment: It creates a recognition listener service which you need to implement to avoid showing a google dialog.

Comment: Does this two lines of code solve my problem? What is "this" in line 2?

Comment: I believe you're seeing a Google dialog with a button at the center for mic. If that is the dialog you're seeing this here is your solution(first 2 lines).
The first line creates a speech recognizer and second line registers a listener to all recognition callbacks. You need to replace "this" a recogntion listener implementation where you need to implement various methods like "onPartialResults()", "onResults()" etc (you may look it up).
Hope this clears your doubts!

Comment: No. in my case, popup opens for select tts engine

Comment: When I had written this answer, I had it working without any dialogs. Sorry buddy I'm not sure of the behavior on the recent versions of android.